# How to use properly such generic person pronouns as one, people, you, we, and they

Tags: personal-pronouns

When writing about a general topic in emails, essays, business correspondence or whatever, I often wonder which  generic person pronoun to use. My quick Google search for sample sentences using such pronouns as one, people, you etc. returned a lot of examples, but I haven't been able to figure out any rules or general tendency in them.

Is there any common ground of understanding among native English speakers when to use "one", "people", "you" etc?

The following are just some sample sentences I checked during my Google search.

> [***One*** cannot choose the period of history in which ***one*** lives.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-16570637)

> [***PEOPLE*** OFTEN CAN'T JUDGE HOW ***THEY*** IMPRESS OTHERS](https://www.nytimes.com/1987/06/30/science/people-often-can-t-judge-how-they-impress-others.html)

> [***You*** will never know the particular virus that gets ***you***.](https://www.theaustralian.com.au/world/the-times/coronavirus-what-covid19-does-to-your-body/news-story/62870adf03540ca39c274bf02411b401)

> [***We*** Have a Cheap, Effective Way to Keep Ourselves Safer From
> COVID-19.](https://time.com/5861295/masks-covid19-spread-fighting/)

> [When ***people*** think “librarian,” ***they say***, “Oh, must be
> kind of dull.”](https://time.com/collection/firsts/4898563/carla-hayden-firsts/)

Comment: 'You will never know the particular virus that gets you' effectively conveys a threat; 'you' hints at confrontation. 'We' connotes solidarity, 'We're all in this together'.

Comment: "One" not only sounds formal but may often sound pretentious, as if the speaker is adopting a lofty and detached viewpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One* is rather formal; OK in a serious essay, but would seem stilted and pretentious in a chatty email.

*People/they* is less formal.

*You* and *we* are informal. Instructions in a conversational tone can be given in the form "First you need to do this..." *We* emphasises the fact that the writer includes themself in the generalisation - "We need to take care...".